# C++/CLI enum not showing up in C# with reference to C++/CLI project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, c++-cli

I can't get the contents of an C++/CLI enum to show up in a C# project.

I can see inside a class I wrote, and even see the enum, but I can't see the enum values. So I can't use the thing on my C# side.

Any reason why contents of a C++/CLI enum wouldn't show up.

My C++/CLI project is compiled as mixed to reuse a C++ library.

And I'm using Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure you used `enum class` to create a .NET-compatible enumeration, and not a native C++ `enum` type.

Later versions of Visual C++ require `public enum class`, to disambiguate from the `enum class` contextual keyword which is part of C++11 (and therefore creates a native type).

Comment: Where am I supposed to figure this out.

Comment: @Xaade: Look at the definition of the enum.  If it looks like `enum X { A, B, C };` you need to change that to `public enum class X { A, B, C };`  You'll also need to change C++/CLI code that uses it, from `A` to `X::A`.

Comment: No no, I understood you, and I understood what to do. I just was wondering how I was supposed to figure that out.

Comment: Ahhh.... there's an overview of C++/CLI keywords here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx.  It's clearly marked that to create a .NET enum you need `enum class`.  C++ native types aren't visible to .NET (except as placeholders), this applies to `enum`, `class`, `struct`, `union`, etc.

Comment: The above linked document appears to have moved, try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/component-extensions-for-runtime-platforms?view=vs-2019   All of the C++/CLI information is sadly now mixed with 3 different flavors of WinRT extensions.

Comment: The compiler does not accept `public enum class` within a class (gives error C3379). Does this mean post-C++11 versions of C++/CLI outright no longer support managed enum classes within classes? **Edit:** Ah, I see the problem: The enum class was declared within a native type...