# public enum class in c++ cli project - Enumeration list from enum outside class visible, but not for enums inside class

Tags: c#, enums, c++-cli

In my c++ project I have an enum I would like to use in my c# code.  I made it an enum class as instructed in other stackoverflow articles, like [C++/CLI enum not showing up in C# with reference to C++/CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031439/c-cli-enum-not-showing-up-in-c-sharp-with-reference-to-c-cli-project)

The issue is, if the enum class is inside another class, I can see the enum itself, but not its enumeration list. So in c++

```
public enum class cool {Cool1, Cool2};
```

The following is OK in c#

```
cool whatLevelCool;
whatLevelCool = cool.Cool1;
```

Works fine in my c# code - I can see the cool enum and access cool.Cool1, and cool.cool2.

However, if it is embedded in a class, even though it is in the public section, only the enum itself is visible, but not its enumeration list. So,

```
public class SuperCool{
    public:
        enum class cool {Cool1, Cool2};
...
```

In this case if i go to my c# code,

```
SuperCool.cool whatLevelCool;          //Still works fine
whatLevelCool = SuperCool.cool.Cool1;  //Doesn't work - enum has no values in it
```

What gives? Is my only option to pull the enums outside of the class, or is there another way?

The code with the enums is not my code, and the enums are used all over, so I'd like to avoid moving them if possible.

Comment: It is not a managed enum.  Tends to be confusing because of C++11, it added several keywords that were already used in C++/CLI.  `enum class` was one of them.  Only prefixing `public` can convince the compiler that it needs to be a managed enum that can also be used in C# code.

Comment: I tried to put public before it, but it's not valid inside of the c++ class.  Ended up just moving it outside of the class, where public enum Class works, wasn't much to change after all.  

Thanks for the help.